# Equivalent of SQL's numeric(15,2) on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, numeric

What would be a accurate equivalent of SQL's numeric(15,2) on MySQL? I've tried decimal(15,2) and it's not working as it should.

Comment: By "working as it should" you mean...?

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql if you say `decimal(5,2)` then you got field which can contain max `999.99` (so its total 5 and 2 after decimal point.)